# NSTableView with custom cell view and NSArrayController bindings drawing a blank string

Tags: swift, cocoa

It took me forever to figure out how to set up editing on a custom cell view for an `NSTableView`.  Thanks to StackOverflow I figured that much out.  P.S. I was doing all of this in Interface Builder.

I have a single column table in which the cell is a custom multi-control `NSTableCellView`, with:

- `name` (in bold)
- `description`
- `detail`

It's all text.  Set up editability on the `name` only.  The table is sorted by the name.

When I edit the `name`, it has the effect on the bound model that I expect.  The table even re-sorts correctly.  However, it's displaying incorrectly.  The `description` and `detail` (not editable) still show up correctly, but the `name` (which was edited) is a blank.  When I inspect the model, it has the correct updated value.  But the cell view itself is incorrect.

This doesn't happen all the time--it typically happens if the cell is re-sorted to the top or bottom of the table, but that may be a red herring and may instead have to do with `NSTableView` cell caching or something.

I hacked up a workaround in which I assign a delegate to the `NSTextField` (automatically generated for the `NSTableCellView`) and intercept the `textShouldEndEditing` event.  For some reason this event is getting triggered twice for a given edit (after I press "enter" in the text field)--once for the actual edit where `fieldEditor.string` is different from the model name, followed by another event where `fieldEditor.string` is the same as the model name.  If I return `false` for my `textShouldEndEditing` handler in the latter case, then the cell contents end up being drawn correctly.  That's the hack.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong here though, and that shouldn't be necessary.

Is the `textShouldEndEditing` event supposed to be fired twice?

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. I've hit the same problem (which I believe only appeared on 10.11) and couldn't find a solution. I've already though of going into manual mode, without bindings. The only minor problem with this method is that I hear a beep after editing is finished, probably because it returns NO the second time. Oh, well.